# MTD and YTD of Sales SQL

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table called Sales_History

What I need to be able to do is populate a YTD and a MTD for certain sales peoples.

Fields i have to play with are :

Salesperson_Invoiced (needs to be grouped by)
NetNet_Revenue_Func (need MTD and YTD figure)
GM_Func_Net (need MTD and YTD figure)
some other fields ive used in a  where clause

my first atempt was this :

```
Select t.Salesperson_Invoiced,
  Sum(y.NetNet_Revenue_Func) YTD_REV,
  Sum(m.NetNet_Revenue_Func) MTD_REV
  From Sales_History t
   join Sales_History y
      on y.Salesperson_Invoiced = t.Salesperson_Invoiced
         and datediff(year, y.TranDate, t.TranDate) = 0 
         and y.TranDate <= t.TranDate
   join Sales_History m
      on m.Salesperson_Invoiced = t.Salesperson_Invoiced
         and datediff(month, m.TranDate, t.TranDate) = 0 
         and m.TranDate <= t.TranDate
         where t.PG1 = 'Lighting' and t.Office = 'AU' and t.Year = '2021'
Group by t.Salesperson_Invoiced, t.TranDate
```

but this did not give me what i wanted :(

Want i want to see is something like :

```
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Salesperson_Invoiced | NetNet_Revenue_Func MTD | NetNet_Revenue_Func YTD | GM_Func_Net MTD | GM_Func_Net YTD |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| James                | 500                     | 600                     |                 |                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| John                 | 600                     | 700                     |                 |                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Peter                | 700                     | 800                     |                 |                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Harry                | 800                     | 900                     |                 |                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Potter               | 900                     | 1000                    |                 |                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I know the code above only has NetNet_Revenue_Func thought i would get one workign first before adding the other.

If anyone can please let me know what im doing wrong or tell me if im going about this all wrong that would be great ! :)

Hello All,

I have re worked the code a little to the following thanks to Squirel

Would this be the best possible way to do what i'm doing :)?

```
Select  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func 
                 End) MTD_REV
From    Sales_History t
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = Year(getdate())
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced
```

---

Update -

Here is a working SQL

```
Select  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,        
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) MTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) MTD_GM,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
                SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) YTD_GM
From    Sales_History t
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = Year(getdate())
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced
```

Is it possible for me to add the follow

is it possible for me to add the following

```
SELECT Salesperson_1,sum(Value_Func) as BO_AUD
FROM Datawarehouse.dbo.Open_Orders
where Office = 'AU' and PG1 = 'Lighting'
group by Salesperson_1
```

so I can have it look like this ?

```
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| Salesperson_Invoiced | NetNet_Revenue_Func MTD | NetNet_Revenue_Func YTD | GM_Func_Net MTD | GM_Func_Net YTD | BO_AUD |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| James                | 500                     | 100                     |                 |                 |        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| John                 | 600                     | 200                     |                 |                 |        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| Peter                | 700                     | 300                     |                 |                 |        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| Harry                | 800                     | 400                     |                 |                 |        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
| Potter               | 900                     | 1                       |                 |                 |        |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: You probably just need to remove the "t.TranDate" from your GROUP BY ...

Comment: Hey Craig,

I did try this but it didn't work :(

Numbers blow up massivly 

Example if i use that whole code 

Sales Person X YTD = 409451114.58
Sales Person X MTD = 227982644.95

if i use this code :

```select Salesperson_Invoiced, SUM(NetNet_Revenue_Func) as 'YTD'
from Sales_History 
where PG1 = 'Lighting' and Office = 'AU' and Year = '2021'
group by Salesperson_Invoiced```

Which I believe is YTD

Sales Person X YTD = 251596.89 which is correct.

Comment: Yeah, you're right actually,  I wasn't really thinking clearly.  Obviously, Squirrel has an answer below that would suit.  Your JOIN approach would work if you derived a CTE first with the unique Salesperson_Invoiced values and JOINed on that

Comment: Thanks for your help Craig! Squirrel has hit the nail on the head of what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirement, you can simplified your query to below.

You don't need to `JOIN` the `Sales_History` multiple times. You can use `CASE` expression to perform the conditional `SUM()` to get the `MTD` value. Assuming by MTD you mean current month

```
Select  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,
        Sum(t.NetNet_Revenue_Func) YTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TransDate) = Month(getdate()) 
                 Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func 
                 End) MTD_REV
From    Sales_History t
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = 2021
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced
```

For YTD calculation, you can use below expression.

```
SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) 
          Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func 
          End) YTD_REV
```

Since you have the `Year` column in the table, I am using that. Else you can also do

```
SUM (Case When Year(t.TransDate) = Year(getdate()) 
          Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func 
          End) YTD_REV
```

Anyway, for performance reason, you should also filtered the required period in the `WHERE` like what you are doing now with `t.Year = 2021`

EDIT : Also fixed the table alias typo error in earlier query.
Note : Your `Year` column in the table should be `int` right ? So you don't need to use single quote on the year `And t.Year = 2021`

Comment: Yep you are correct that MTD i mean Month to Date.

For some reason i cant get your code to work :( 

I have a squiggle under "Then"

Also what would be the best way to have it check the year so i dont need to adjsut the code every year where year = 2021 was to make it run faster

Comment: please add to your question the query that you used, so that we can help to check

Comment: Updated the query

Comment: hey Squirrel,

I have used your code and played around with it adding the get date into the where.

Do you think this will be the best way ?

Comment: based on the limited known information, this is the simplest way

Comment: after adding in "GM_Func_Net" MTD and YTD this is exactly what i needed :)

Thanks heaps!!

Just a question... once we hit 2022 i would not need to change anything right ?

Also if i was to join another table (back orders) onto this if i link it onto Salesperson_Invoiced can you see any issues occurring ?

Comment: as long as you don't hard code the date in the query you don't need to change anything. Make sure the `WHERE` clause is using `WHERE t.Year = Year(getdate())` to check for current year